# Why do so many programs use "X" in their title, is this a convention that I am not aware of?

Tags: filenames

I might be misunderstanding, but OS X as an operating system, as well as programs like X11 (terminal program), Xming (visual interfacing with other servers), Xcode, and countless others that I can't think of at the moment. Is this a convention or some deeper meaning behind it?

Comment: X= may the force be with you....

Answer (score 4):

It refers to the [X Window System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System), one of the first graphical environments on UNIX.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing particular.

X11 is the X Window System, just the name it was given.

Xcode was released in Mac OS X, so likely took it's name from there (a few other theories [here](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-Xcode-named-Xcode))

Mac OS X is using X in the form of the Roman numeral X, meaning 10.

Another notable example, Adobe Reader X (and subsequently XI) are due to the Roman numeral also, being version 10 and 11.

Some utilities will be referencing the X in Mac OS X, others may be the X in X11, others, I guess, just think X is a cool letter to use.